# running a batch file automatically

Tags: batch-file, sqlcmd

I am trying to run a batch file but it stops at the first step.

When I run it manually in the cmd step by step, it works, but I want to schedule it to run automatically. The following is the code in the batchfile.

```
cd\
sqlcmd
1>Use PilotReportDB
2>Go
1>Exec dbo.sp_SalesImport
2>Go
1>Exit
```

When I double click the batch file it opens the cmd showing:

```
C:\>sqlcmd
1>_
```

How can I get it to run this code?

Comment: you need the commands in separate file (e.g `myscript.sql`) and call it like `sqlcmd -S myServer\instanceName -i C:\myScript.sql` ->https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170572.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @npocmaka That would make a great answer.